# Paging doesn't work?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, navigation, pagination

I have my own custom post type, and 15 items there.

This code shows all the items:

```
<?php   $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'my_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 15 ) );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
(...)
```

When I change posts_per_page to "5" there should be 3 pages, but it displays only  5 items and there are no other pages (or at least I don't know how to access them).

This code displays nothing:

```
<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
  {menu or any html code}
<?php endif; ?>
```

Maybe I do something wrong? I have the whole code/loop in page-myposttype.php file.

I've tried this code:

```
   $temp = $wp_query;
    $loop= null;
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',   
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'posts_per_page' => 2 ) );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

But no luck... When I type wordpress/my_post_type/page/2 (page/3 etc.) manually I see other pages and they work & look fine. But I'm unable to echo the default navi... :(

Comment: where is your code to print out the next/previus page link?

Comment: Your query uses `$loop`, but you check the number of pages of `$wp_query`. `$wp_query` will contain the default query, which is probably a page in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered a question that's virtually identical to this very recently on the WordPress.org forums.

[Custom Post Type Archive Page - Pagination Isn't Working](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-archive-page-pagination-isnt-working)

I've provided a work-around / fix in that thread that should also work for you to.

:)

**EDIT:** You also need to add the paging parameter to your query..

Eg.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type', 
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 15, 
);
$loop = new WP_Query;
$loop->query( $args );
```

I reformatted the code to make it a little more readable, end result will be the same.

Comment: I'm using wp_pagenavi and it doesn't help me at all :( Eeven with your code when I click Next/Prev Entry - I'm getting the same items all over again (for example if there are 6 items and I display 2, I'm getting 3 pages of items number 1 and 2).

Comment: That's because you're missing the paging parameter in your query, i'll add it into my answer.

Comment: your answer was very helpful and works fine but I BADLY need to display the default Wordpress pagination/page navigation. Do you have any ideas how to achieve that? I'm using wp_pagenavi plugin based on the default WP navigation and it doesn't "work" with your code.

Comment: nvm, figured it out (had to put pagenavi code instead of default links), thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out and i'm happy to have helped... :)